# RestKit: What delegate method is called for postObject?

Tags: ios, restkit

What method of RKObjectLoaderDelegate gets called after the method `- (RKObjectLoader *)postObject:(id<NSObject>)object delegate:(id<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>)delegate` is called?

I'm trying to run some more code once my POST is successful.

**EDIT (more info):**

Neither of the methods that @Paul mentions are being called, but my server is interpreting the POST somewhat correctly because the DB is being written to.

During app initialization, I am doing the following:

```
// Grab the reference to the router from the manager
RKObjectRouter *router = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router;

// Define a default resource path for all unspecified HTTP verbs
[router routeClass:[EventMessage class] toResourcePath:@"/events_messages/:idPrimaryKey"];
[router routeClass:[EventMessage class] toResourcePath:@"/event_messages" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

And when I am ready to POST, I am doing this:

```
RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[EventMessage class]];
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"user_id" toAttribute:@"userId"];
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"event_id" toAttribute:@"eventId"];
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"message" toAttribute:@"message"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider registerMapping:objectMapping withRootKeyPath:@"event_message"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:eventMessage delegate:self];
```

And this is the error that I get in the console:

> Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'." UserInfo=0x7b9f510 {JKAtIndexKey=0, JKLineNumberKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects;
```

or

```
    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
```

Comment: Hi Paul.  I added more info.  Neither of these methods are being called.

Comment: turn the tracing on like Besi says.

Comment: I think that my serialization mapping was wrong.  One of the two methods above are now called correctly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have setup your mappings correctly the posting of objects is very easy. Like Paul Cezanne pointed out, the corresponding callbacks will be used.

For posting objects, however, you'll also need a serialisation mapping that tells the framework which parameters should be converted to POST parameters:

Mapping Example:

```
    // Serialisation Mapping
    RKObjectMapping *messageSendMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];

    [messageSendMapping mapAttributes:@"name", @"number", @"text", nil];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider
            setSerializationMapping:messageSendMapping
                           forClass:[Message class]];
```

**Update:** For trouble shooting purposes you might want to increase the log level for RestKit like so:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

Comment: Hi Besi.  I added some code.  Is it expected that if the serialization mapping is wrong, neither `didLoadObjects` nor `didFailWithError` will be called?

Comment: I would expect that `didFailWithError` would be called. What you might do as well is to do more fine-grained logging with RestKit (See my updated answer).

Comment: I've got a similar issue and logging shows no errors. It just seems to fire off the request but then nothing else happens. I can post a request using the shared client and that comes back but [RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:foo delegate:self] doesn't call any of my delegate functions. Turning up logging shows no errors.

Comment: Similarly if I call `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:foo usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) { NSLog(@"this never fires"); }];` the block doesn't execute.

Comment: Ah so turns out that `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` doesn't self init you have to do that yourself. Same goes for RKObjectManager's router. For some reason I though they'd be constructed for me. It just goes to show if somethings not working make sure you're not sending messages to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that RKObjectManager has been initialized:

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com";
RKObjectManager* mgr = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:url];
```

I wasted a bunch of time before noticing that sharedManager is not really a singleton, you have to initialize it.

After that you can use the sharedManager and get an reference to the first one created:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:mapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/RKKeyValueMappingExample"];
```

Comment: The `sharedManager` is a singleton nevertheless but you have to initialize it yourself because RestKit needs to know the `baseURL`

Comment: Besi, it's really not. Typically a singleton restricts creation so there's only a single instance. Since you can create multiple managers this is a different pattern. I totally get what you're saying about needing the URL for initalization though.