# RKObjectLoaderDelegate methods not called with post:params:delegate:

Tags: restkit

I am able to get all the required RKObjectLoaderDelegate methods called when doing a GET with loadObjectsAtResourcePath:delegate:.

However, when I am doing a POST with post:params:delegate:, only request:didLoadResponse: gets called. Even methods such as objectLoader:didLoadObjects: and objectLoader:didFailWithError: are not getting called.

Here is the code snippet.

```
    self.appObjectManager.client = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:self.webServiceURLString];
    [self.appObjectManager.client setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [self.appObjectManager.client setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

    RKObjectMapping* sessionInformationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[sessionInformation class]];
    [sessionInformationMapping mapKeyPath:@"uid" toAttribute:@"userID"];
    [self.appObjectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:sessionInformationMapping forKeyPath:@"user"];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc", @"pwd", nil]
                                                                         forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"password", nil]];

    [self.appObjectManager.client post:resourcePath params:parameters delegate:self];
```

I found a similar question here, but it doesn't seem to help me.
[RestKit: What delegate method is called for postObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307649/restkit-what-delegate-method-is-called-for-postobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of post:params:delegate:

```
[self.appObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader) {
  loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
  loader.params = params;
  loader.delegate = self;
}];
```

The objectLoader delegate methods should get called when the response returns.